# Get a rolling count of timestamps in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, group-by, recursive-query

I have a table (in an Oracle DB) that looks something like what is shown below with about 4000 records. This is just an example of how the table is designed. The timestamps range for several years.

```
|        Time                    |    Action      |
|   9/25/2019 4:24:32 PM         |      Yes       |
|   9/25/2019 4:28:56 PM         |      No        |  
|   9/28/2019 7:48:16 PM         |      Yes       |
|         ....                   |     ....       |
```

I want to be able to get a count of timestamps that occur on a rolling 15 minute interval. My main goal is to identify the maximum number of timestamps that appear for any 15 minute interval. I would like this done by looking at each timestamp and getting a count of timestamps that appear within 15 minutes of that timestamp.

My goal would to have something like

```
|      Interval                             |              Count          |
| 9/25/2019 4:24:00 PM - 9/25/2019 4:39:00  |               2             |
| 9/25/2019 4:25:00 PM - 9/25/2019 4:40:00  |               2             |
|            .....                          |             .....           |
| 9/25/2019 4:39:00 PM - 9/25/2019 4:54:00  |               0             |
```

I am not sure how I would be able to do this, if at all. Any ideas or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused on how you are defining "15 minute" interval.  It is not based on the clock.

Comment: basically from my very first time stamp to my very last time stamp is the range. In between there I want to look at every rolling 15 minute interval. What I mean by rolling is like minute 0-15, minute 1-16, minute 2-17... and so on. It will take a long time to execute this, but I need the information

Comment: . . You should define the time intervals based on the times in the *data*.  Generating time intervals over the course of years at the spacing of 1 minute is simply not needed to get the max count that you claim to want.

Comment: I understand. and that is fine to do it that way too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want any 15 minute interval in the data, then you can use:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (order by timestamp
                      range between interval '15' minute preceding and current row
                     ) as cnt_15
from t;
```

If you want the maximum, then use `rank()` on this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, rank() over (order by cnt_15 desc) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   count(*) over (order by timestamp
                                  range between interval '15' minute preceding and current row
                                 ) as cnt_15
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This doesn't produce exactly the results you specify in the query.  But it does answer the question:

> I want to be able to get a count of timestamps that occur on a rolling 15 minute interval. My main goal is to identify the maximum number of timestamps that appear for any 15 minute interval.

Comment: I am not familiar with the range between. For some reason it does not like minute. It says there is a missing keyword. I may be translating it to my specific design incorrectly. Do you have a link for documentation?

Comment: @newwebdev22 . . . Oops.  It was missing the `interval` keyword.

Comment: ahh makes sense. I got the first one to run. Can you explain how it is working?

Comment: I tweaked the first query just a tad to get what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: @newwebdev22 . . . This is called a windowing clause (in Oracle, the more common name is "window frame" I think):  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174.

Comment: perfect. I got it now! This is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You could enumerate the minutes with a recursive query, then bring the table with a `left join`:

```
with recursive cte (start_dt, max_dt) as (
    select trunc(min(time), 'mi'), max(time) from mytable
    union all
    select start_dt + interval '1' minute, max_dt from cte where start_dt < max_dt
)
select 
    c.start_dt,
    c.start_dt + interval '15' minute end_dt,
    count(t.time) cnt
from cte c
left join mytable t 
    on  t.time >= c.start_dt 
    and t.time <  c.start_dt + interval '15' minute
group by c.start_dt
```

Comment: It accomplishes what I asked for, but is slow. I have edited my question